# Cocoa Pods not updating inside of app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoapods

I have been assigned at work to update an app that hasn't been touched in a year and a half. The cocoa pods version is 0.22.

I am trying to update it to 0.35. I've run 'sudo gem update' and have .35, but when I run 'pod install' it just installs the old versions of all of the pods (i.e. AFNetworking 1.1.0).

Thanks

```
    platform :ios, '6.0'

    pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'OpenCV'
    pod 'RestKit'
    pod 'QuickDialog'
    pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'Mixpanel'
    pod 'GVUserDefaults'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
    pod 'uservoice-iphone-sdk'

    target :ShoeboxTests, :exclusive => true do
       pod 'Kiwi', :head
    end
```

I'm new to using cocoa pods so I'm not sure what to do with this file.

Comment: Can you add your Podfile code?

Comment: AFNetworking isn't even in your podfile; weird example. What version of these pods is being installed that are old?

Comment: I used AFnetworking because it says it's installing it.Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking 1.1.0 (was 1.1.0)
Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK 3.5.0 (was 3.5.0)
Installing GVUserDefaults 0.9.0 (was 0.9.0)
Installing JRSwizzle 1.0 (was 1.0)
Installing Kiwi HEAD based on 2.3.1 (was HEAD based on 2.0.5)
Installing Mixpanel 2.0.0 (was 2.0.0)
Installing OpenCV 2.4.3.2 (was 2.4.3.2)
Installing QuickDialog 0.8 (was 0.8)
Installing ReactiveCocoa 1.5.0 (was 1.5.0)

Comment: AFNetworking and JRSwizzle aren't in your podfile, so can you check some things? Did you edit the podfile? If so, save the pod file then do pod install (or pod update). Double check that you are in the same directory as this podfile.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the file and I am for sure in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your podfile specifies that you're targeting iOS 6, so it is possible that cocoapods is only giving you the highest version known to support iOS 6.

Try removing that line entirely, or changing it to:

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
```

Comment: This was part of it. First I had to run 'pod update', not just "sudo gem update'. Then this was the next problem I had to fix. Thanks.